# Download an APK from a website and prompt the installation to the user

Tags: android, download, google-play, apk, google-play-services

My approach is simple, I have an APK hosted on my site and when the user completes the download I would like to present the installation wizard instead of having to look for the file in downloads or even using a file manager for older devices etc.

Is that possible to be achieved for non-PlayStore apps?

Has anybody done this before? Could you shed some light please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that functionality is handled by the user's browser, and none automatically install apks (and right so, as that would lead to many malware).

Comment: I don't want it to install without the user's intervention I just want the installer to popup and not have to browse the file which is not practical for so many users. Any suggestion?

Comment: as I said, that is the user's browser decision: what to do with a file the user downloads. There might be android browsers out there that let the user run/open the file immediately or the user might have a download manager that does that but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Fair enough, however once you have the app you can treat new updates and then fire up the installer right? At least this is what I get from some forums. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: if the app is not in play store, for updates, you will have to manually implement that functionality on your app. As an example, after a quich search i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically